# AutoScaling an image and paragraph to fit the document iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Im using iTextSharp 5.5.13.2. What my program is doing is generate a new PDF, which will load inside multiple pdfs and a paragraph to each document page. The issue is that I want to make it fit the whole document but is leaving a space, tried multiple ways like:

· Adding a table and two cells makes the first cell fit the full document, the second one is on other page.
· Adding a table and one cell makes a Document Exception.

Working code but happens as said on the first point:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> key in dict)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(key.Key);

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
                table.WidthPercentage = 100;

                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(page), true);
                cell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
                //cell.AddElement(new Phrase(key.Value));
                PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(key.Value));
                cell2.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

                table.AddCell(cell);
                table.AddCell(cell2);

                document.Add(table);
                document.NewPage();
            }
        }
```

How could I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this code, what I've done is add both cells to a table and reduce the WidthPercentage so all fit into one page.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> key in dict)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(key.Key);

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
                table.WidthPercentage = 68;
                if (key.Value.Contains("word"))
                    table.WidthPercentage = 65;

                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(page), true);
                cell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
                //cell.AddElement(new Phrase(key.Value));
                PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(key.Value));
                cell2.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;


                table.AddCell(cell);
                table.AddCell(cell2);
                
                document.Add(table);
                document.NewPage();
            }
        }
```